# Unity Project now requires IL2CPP

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, il2cpp

After updating Unity, a hololens project created (and working) in Unity 5, now has its scripting backend set to IL2CPP. (I ignore what was the original setting)

How did this happen? and What are the implications?(I need to debug the project) Can I safely switch the platform to .NET?

Answer (score 2):

Unity is deprecating the .NET scripting backend in favor of IL2CPP and the newer versions automatically have IL2CPP selected as the scripting backend.  You can still run .NET as the scripting backend for now but it might be a good idea to get used to the IL2CPP scripting backend as .NET will be dropped in the future.  There is a managed debugger for IL2PCPP in 2018.2 that is supposed to allow you to debug your managed code (versus the C++ that it is converted to) but I don't know much about it yet.

Comment: I read something like this lately but I also read that Hololens projects will remain .NET for the time being. If Unity deprecates .NET I wonder how do Hololens projects be affected?...

Comment: You will just need to start using the IL2CPP scripting backend which actually has more of the .NET surface available then the current .NET scripting backend.  The IL2CPP scripting backend basically takes your IL and converts it to CPP before compiling (Hence IL2CPP). I have a Hololens project that I recently ported to IL2CPP and there were a few kinks but overall it makes sense for Unity to focus on just one scripting backend for everyone rather than trying to keep the .NET scripting backend support.